# Adding a hyperlink dynamically in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (i = 0; i < cRowCount / 5; i++) {
    link = $('<a/>').attr({
        href : '#',
        id : $(this).attr('id') + (i + 1),
        class: 'myLink'
    });

    $(this).append(link + "&nbsp;");
}
```

When I am appending the link to my component it is not giving me the link. Instead it is showing following thing that to without a hyperlink.

```
 [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

Comment: You concat object and string. Result is string "[object Object] ". Remove " + "&nbsp;"

Comment: Also, use `var link`! Otherwise, you create unitialised global variable. This will cause you lot of trouble when simultaneous loops run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem with this line `$(this).append(link + "&nbsp;");` this line converting your object into string, because you are appending object with string

you can do this

HTML

```
<div>abc
</div>
```

Code to append

```
for (i = 0; i < 10 / 5; i++) {
    link = $('<a/>').attr({
    href : '#',
    id : $(this).attr('id') + (i + 1),
    class: 'myLink'
     });
    link.html(i );

$("div").append(link );
    $("div").html($("div").html() + "&nbsp;" );
}
```

## JsFiddle DEMO

Comment: @RachitMGarg - actually it just and example how you can do it and remove the error you are getting....I think you need to accept proper answerand understand the things given in answer..

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that it returns an array of 1 element. Try doing `$(this).append(link[0] + "&nbsp;");`